# Bash: date and ge operation throwing an error

Tags: bash, shell

I have following script where i am trying to subtract two date values

```
date1=$(date -d "$LogDate1" +%s)
date2=$(date -d "$LogDate2" +%s)

if [ $date1 -ge $date2 ]; then
    Check=PASS
else
    Check=FAIL
fi
```

While executing the script I am getting the following error:

```
date: extra operand ‘INFO’
Try 'date --help' for more information.

./script1.sh: line 4: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

Comment: It reads like one of the `LogDate` items is not a valid parseable date string? This would explain the error - one of `date1` and `date2` is empty.

Comment: What's output of `declare -p LogDate1 LogDate2` ?

Comment: `set -x` and https://www.shellcheck.net are your friends.